# Hibernate java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I want to extract all events from db wherein User joined.

DAO :

```
public List<Event> getUserJoinedEvents(User user) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("FROM Event event WHERE event.eventMembersJoined = :user")
                .setParameter("user", user).list();
```

Entity:

```
...  
 @JoinTable(name="MEMBERS_JOINED_EVENT", 
                        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="JOINED_EVENT_ID")}, 
                        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")})
        private Set<User> eventMembersJoined = new HashSet<User>();
...
```

And as result got exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eventMembersJoined` is a `Set`, but you compare it using `=` with parameter of type `User`. 
To check weather a set contains certain element, try with this:

```
FROM Event event WHERE :user in elements(event.eventMembersJoined)
```